How to ask for a raise as a babysitter
I am a 55-year-old woman who has been watching kids most of my adult life. I babysit for a family with a 1 1/2 yr old. I have been watching her since she was 5 months old. I have been watching her for a year and am not sure how much to ask. I am currently getting $25 an hour and live in Los Angeles. I also just found out that they are expecting another child in June. Any advice on How much of a raise I should ask for?

@BartvanIngenSchenau similar questions exist on here, this is but one https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/8655/36241, so will you migrate all of them?
